# How to overhang "logo" from nav

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to figure out how to overhang a logo from the Navbar using SVGs.

this is my codepen example: https://codepen.io/Stefan_K/pen/qYweej

HTML/ Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px
}
```

The example is what I have managed to do so far. I am trying to overhang the logo (yellow circle) under the navigation - half in, half out and keep the default height of the navbar.

Comment: you would have to make the svg `position: absolute` to take it out of the document flow so it doesn't affect the height of your nav. then you would have to play with your `top` values and give the nav some `padding-left` so it doesn't overlap the nav items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with:

```
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    margin-left: 115px;
}
```

and remove all styles from svg

https://codepen.io/Yulia_pi/pen/vjwELy

Answer (score 1):

See updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYGEOd)

Updated CSS

```
nav {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
.navbar.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse{
 margin-left : 80px;
}
```